# Why does placing an order returns a MySQL Duplicate Entry?

Tags: magento-2.1, magento-2.1.3

I have tested a payment gateway on a fresh magento 2.1.3 install with sample data and it works well.

Unfortunately when implemented on your site it does not.

The payment gateway flow is:

- `Select payment method`
- `Place Order` - `$this->orderRepository->save($order);` is called in `OrderService.php`
- Redirected to the payment gateway website to enter details
- Goes to success page and updates the order with `$this->orderRepository->save($order);` again...however **this time it breaks with an error**

The error is:

```
    SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
 '1000000279-1' for key 'SALES_ORDER_INCREMENT_ID_STORE_ID', query was: 
INSERT INTO `sales_order` (`state`, `status`, `protect_code`, 
`shipping_description`, `is_virtual`, `store_id`, `customer_id`, 
`base_discount_amount`, `base_grand_total`, `base_shipping_amount`, 
`base_shipping_tax_amount`, `base_subtotal`, `base_tax_amount`, 
`base_to_global_rate`, `base_to_order_rate`, `discount_amount`, 
`grand_total`, `shipping_amount`, `shipping_tax_amount`, 
`store_to_base_rate`, `store_to_order_rate`, `subtotal`, `tax_amount`, 
`total_qty_ordered`, `customer_is_guest`, `customer_note_notify`, 
`customer_group_id`, `quote_id`, `base_shipping_discount_amount`, 
`base_subtotal_incl_tax`, `base_total_due`, `shipping_discount_amount`, 
`subtotal_incl_tax`, `total_due`, `weight`, `increment_id`, 
`applied_rule_ids`, `base_currency_code`, `customer_email`, 
`customer_firstname`, `customer_lastname`, `customer_middlename`, 
`discount_description`, `global_currency_code`, `order_currency_code`, 
`remote_ip`, `shipping_method`, `store_currency_code`, `store_name`, 
`total_item_count`, `discount_tax_compensation_amount`, 
`base_discount_tax_compensation_amount`, 
`shipping_discount_tax_compensation_amount`, `shipping_incl_tax`, 
`base_shipping_incl_tax`, `gift_message_id`, `mageworx_fee_amount`, 
`base_mageworx_fee_amount`, `mageworx_fee_tax_amount`, 
`base_mageworx_fee_tax_amount`, `mageworx_fee_details`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, 
?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 
?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 
?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

This exception is thrown on `line 191 of /vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Service/OrderService.php`

I think this has to do with the `increment_id` and the `eav_entity_store` table

My environment:

- PHP 7.0
- Magento 2.1.3
- Using migrated data using the magento `data-migration-tool` from magento 1 site

**Update**

After a bit of investigation I found that the intial order creation on place order sets an `order_id` with the `reserveOrderId()` function. Once payment is successful another order is created with a different reserveOrderId as `$this->getReservedOrderId()` in `Quote.php` is falsey.

However on the migrated database `$this->getReservedOrderId()` is set or is truthy. That is why it tries to create a new order with the old order_id and mysql has issues.

Comment: This thread has a lot of info on the topic https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6929#issuecomment-252723067

Comment: It is creating a new order with an `increment_id` that already exists. Better to get the order.